# Firebase query not pushing data if node is deleted then added back

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data initially:

```
 "holidays": {
    ...
    "2016-12-19": {
      "stegosaurus": true
    },
    "2016-12-20": {
      "lambeosaurus": true,
      "stegosaurus": true
    },
    "2016-12-21": {
      "lambeosaurus": true
    },
    ...
  }
```

With the following queries,

```
ref.orderByKey().startAt("2016-12-18")
                 .endAt("2016-12-18")
                 .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                    console.log("child_added")
                 });
ref.orderByKey().startAt("2016-12-18")
                 .endAt("2016-12-18")
                 .on("child_removed", function(snapshot) {
                    console.log("child_removed")
                 });
 ref.orderByKey().startAt("2016-12-18")
                 .endAt("2016-12-18")
                 .on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
                    console.log("child_changed")
                 });
 ref.orderByKey().startAt("2016-12-18")
                 .endAt("2016-12-18")
                 .on("child_moved", function(snapshot) {
                    console.log("child_moved")
                 });
```

On initial adding of a new node, "2016-12-18" to the "holidays" node, I get a `child_added` event. When the node "2016-12-18" gets deleted, I get a `child_removed` event. But when I then add back "2016-12-18", this time i do not receive any events. Is this a firebase bug?

Here is a jsbin that duplicates this problem:
https://jsbin.com/sefaha/6/edit?html,console,output

To reproduce:

```
1) On reload, Click Update button 
2) Dino info is displayed
3) Click Delete button
4) Dino info is removed
5) Click Update button
6) Dino info is not displayed anymore
7) Reload/refresh browser
8) Dino info is displayed
9) Click Delete button
10) Repeat step (1)
```

Please note that in step (1), sometimes dino info is not displayed. It seems that it depends on number of clients being connected.

Comment: None of the code you shared is actually adding data, so it's hard to be sure. But in general this part of the Firebase SDK has been quite stable for a while now. It's always possible there is a bug, in which case I'd love to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It'd in general be helpful if you could set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've updated the question with a jsbin to duplicate the issue. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Thanks for tje jsbin. It uses PolymerFire, while your original question was based on the bare Firebase JavaScript SDK. Given that I'm not familiar with the inner workings of PolymerFire (I really should learn more about it, but today is not the day for that), can you reproduce the problem with just the JavaScript SDK?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. I've updated the jsbin link with a snapshot that uses the firebase sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a bug when using deep updates to re-add a node that was previously deleted in the same session. It's been hidden in the Firebase Database server for quite some time and can be reproduced with this snippet:

```
var query = ref.orderByKey().startAt("2017-01-13").endAt("2017-01-13");
// attaching this listener makes it work
//ref.on("value", function(s) { console.log("value", s.val() )});
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) { console.log("child_added"); });
query.on("child_removed", function(snapshot) { console.log("child_removed"); });
query.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) { console.log("child_changed"); });
query.on("child_moved", function(snapshot) { console.log("child_moved"); });
function _update() {
  console.log("updating child");
  ref.update({'2017-01-13/-KaMFzShw40MkBtMypUg': true });
  // using this way of setting the value makes it work
  //ref.child('2017-01-13/-KaMFzShw40MkBtMypUg').set(true);
};
function _delete() {
  console.log("deleting child");
  ref.update({'2017-01-13/-KaMFzShw40MkBtMypUg': null});
};
```

Complete jsbin: https://jsbin.com/zedojum/edit?html,console,output

You can work around the bug by using `set()` instead of update to directly update the lower level child, or by keeping a listener attached to the location (not the query).

I'll post here with instructions when it's been fixed.

Comment: That still appears to be broken, for me. I've written some unit tests for this and have discovered that event listeners on query refs seem to fire only once, unless there are also listeners on a non-query ref for the same key. I'll submit a bug report soonish.

Comment: @cartant Great! Could you please keep me updated on the progress of the bug report? Thanks!

Comment: Just submitted a bug report *"[7-3405000015569] Query ref listeners sometimes fire only once"*.

Comment: Yeah, interestingly enough it indeed stopped working again. Btw: attaching a value listener makes it work as expected (see the updated jsbin).

Comment: As does using a `set()` instead of a deep `update()` call. I added that to my jsbin too. Note that these for the moment both seem work-arounds, but they may allow you to get unstuck.

Comment: Thanks for the workarounds. @cartant May I know how I can track the bug status?

Comment: I don't know if there's a tracker. You'd have to ask @FrankvanPuffelen. This is the first Firebase bug I've reported.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you please kindly advise how I can track the status of the bug? Thanks.

Comment: We confirmed that this is indeed a bug in the Firebase Database. Thanks for finding it, it'd been in there for quite some time! I'll post here with instructions when it's been fixed, in the meantime use one of the approaches I mentioned in my previous comment as a workaround.